# Connecting SSMS client to remote SQL Server instance failing with 'AnyAny' firewall rule

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, windows-firewall, sqlbrowser

How can I connect my SSMS client to a remote SQL Server 2008 R2 instance using SQL browser AND with Windows firewall enabled?

I find that that with the firewall turned off, I can connect fine (without specifying the instance name). Now when I turn the firewall (domain profile) back on, my connection attempts time out. So, to begin my troubleshooting, I created an 'AnyAny' firewall rule however it still failed with a timeout error.

Naturally I can connect fine either way (firewall turned on/off) when I specify the instance name and port. SQL browser is running and listening on UDP 1433. SQL Server is running Windows 2008 R2.

What is getting blocked? And why won't a custom 'AnyAny' rule bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

The information on [this SQLCAT blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2014/02/03/alwayson-availability-groups-listener-named-instances-port-numbers-etc.aspx) might be helpful to you. By default, the SQL Browser service runs on UDP port 1434. If you have a firewall configured on your SQL server, you should open up port 1434 for inbound connections from SSMS.

If you need help setting remote connections to your SQL Server, [this guide is spot on](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx).